# PHPMailer is causing 504 timeout error on my Digital Ocean server using nginx

Tags: php, email, nginx, phpmailer, digital-ocean

I am installing an email-sending capability on one PHP page on my server. I want to be able to specify the gmail account to send from so I am using PHPMailer. However, every time I load the page that sends the email, I get a 504 Gateway timeout error after about 30 seconds. Eventually, the email is sent (I receive it about 5 minutes later) but is this normal? It is a very basic text email.

This is my code to send the email

```
require '../html/lib/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';


//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;

//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "user@gmail.com";

//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "pw";

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('from@gmail.com', 'First Last');

//Set an alternative reply-to address
//$mail->addReplyTo('@example.com', 'First Last');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('recip@gmail.com', 'recip');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test 2';

//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
//$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));

//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->Body = 'This is another plain-text message body';

//Attach an image file
//$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: put in some debug logging, e.g log the time before/after the `send()` call. That's about the only bit of code that could "hang" the process, because that'll be the first time php/phpmailer are reaching "outside" to do something.

Comment: The page times out before loading - how will I see the logs that way? I'm a bit new to debugging in that way

Comment: even something as simple as `error_log('start: '. $start_time)` would log the data to whatever php's configured to use as the error log. the page is loading, but not outputting anything before the timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMTP timeouts are pretty long (at least 5 mins). The 504 you're getting is because the timeout between nginx and your PHP cgi (I'd assume you're running FPM) is shorter, so by the time PHP generates an error, nginx has already dropped the connection, so you're getting no feedback.

It's fairly likely this is a DNS or firewall issue on your host - check out [the troubleshooting docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Comment: That is a very helpful start. Here is the step where I am having trouble: telnet smtp.gmail.com 587. I get a message that says "Trying  2607:....." but then no connection. I am looking into this on the DO side of things now.

Comment: OK so something a bit strange is happening when I try telnet. It says: "Trying 2607:f8b0...." for a long time and then says "Trying 64.233...." (a regular IP address) and seems to connect to gmail just fine at that point.

Comment: FYI I have made a new Stackoverflow question about the telnet issue. Let me know if I should move that back to this one. Thanks

Comment: The telnet problem is that you have an IPv6 address, but apparently no outbound connectivity - so it tries to connect via IPv6, then falls back to IPv4. Either get rid of your IPv6 address, or fix the networking. This may be underlying your PHPMailer problem too.

Comment: I fixed it. Digital Ocean does not allow outgoing IPv6 SMTP but they're bad at publicizing that. It was a simple fix in the end. See here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/outgoing-connections-on-port-25-587-143-blocked-over-ipv6

Comment: Adding in case that disappears: Step 1) nano /etc/gai.conf Step 2)
make the appropriate lines look like this (uncommented!):

precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100 Step 3) Reboot your system

Answer (score 1):

Digital Ocean states in their support center how to enable services like smtp to prioritize connections over IPv4 whilst still maintaining accessible IPv6 functionality to your droplet otherwise.

> You can give priority to IPv4 addresses over IPv6 so that you can
>   continue to send out email without disabling IPv6. You would do that
>   by editing the Droplet's /etc/gai.conf file and removing the comment
>   (#) from the following line:
>
> Default Configuration: #precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100
>
> Configuration with Priority to IPv4: precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100

This has been checked and confirmed working by me for the PHPMailer-issue where request would time out (504 Gateway Time-out) but where the mail is still eventually delivered (Ubuntu 16.04 LEMP).

This is because Ngninx drops the connection to PHP-FPM whilst the php-script is still running in the background trying to resolve an IPv6 SMTP-address, before finally moving over to IPv4 on no-success.