# I recently trying to use mail system but It doesn't work like before

Tags: php, phpmailer

I've once successfully build up my mailing system, but at that time I didn't understand what happen inside of it.

Now, I'm re-building same system, using PHPMailer, and now Gateway Timeout error happens. Please help me to fix my code down here.. What I did is just copy the example and put my account and password.

```
$Mail = new PHPMailer;
$Mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$Mail->IsSMTP(); // Use SMTP
$Mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // Sets SMTP server
$Mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // 2 to enable SMTP debug information
$Mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE; // enable SMTP authentication
$Mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; //Secure conection
$Mail->Port = 587; // set the SMTP port
$Mail->Username = 'myid@gmail.com'; // SMTP account username
$Mail->Password = 'mypassword'; // SMTP account password
$Mail->Priority = 1; // Highest priority - Email priority (1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low)
$Mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$Mail->Encoding = '8bit';
$Mail->Subject = 'SUB';
$Mail->ContentType = 'text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n';
$Mail->From = 'gatesplan@gmail.com';
$Mail->FromName = 'FROM NAME';
$Mail->WordWrap = 900; // RFC 2822 Compliant for Max 998 characters per line

$Mail->AddAddress($email); // To:
$Mail->isHTML(TRUE);
$Mail->Body = "Hi";
$Mail->AltBody = "Hi";
$Mail->Send();
$Mail->SmtpClose();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945676/phpmailer-is-causing-504-timeout-error-on-my-digital-ocean-server-using-nginx

Comment: I don't know where you found this example, but it's very old. Make sure you're using [the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and use the examples provided with it.

Comment: I'm using the latest version I think.. and example that I copied also Inside the example folder. I just make another copy from gmail.phps inside of example folder but it also don't work.